# Linking SQL Server 2014 to Informix Database Results in Architecture Mismatch

Tags: informix, linked-server, sql-server-2014

I am having quite an issue trying to create a linked server in SQL 2014 to Informix.  I have downloaded the IBM Informix SDK 4.10 FC2.  This allowed me to create a 32 bit ODBC in the 64 bit ODBC tool and I was able to register the ifxoledbc.dll with regsvr32.  However, I cannot get the ifxoledbc provider to show up under Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> Providers nor am I able to get the 64 bit ODBC set up under 64 bit.  Every time I try to set up a linked server to the 32 bit ODBC I get an architecture mismatch error which I expect.  I don't care whether I use the ifxoledbc driver directly for the linked server setup or use an ODBC connection for the linked server setup.  Either one will work for my purposes of reading from the Informix database, but I just can't seem to get past the 64 bit crap!

Has anyone been able to set up a linked server to Informix on a 64 bit server?

I realize the question has already been posed here almost a year ago: [ODBC connection from 64-bit SQL Server to Informix data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530257/informix-odbc-connection-to-64-bit-sql-server?rq=1)
But the answers to that question were not specific enough to help me.  The guy who provided the screenshots did not say what he did to get the provider to show up.

I was going to post screenshots of the 64 bit ODBC showing that the DSN is 32 bit platform and a screenshot of the options I have when I try to add a new System DSN in the 64 bit version of ODBC (note that I cannot choose the IBM Informix ODBC Driver), but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Actually, I misspoke.  I downloaded the IBM Informix SDK 4.10 FC5 developer edition located here: http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/preconfig.jsp?id=2011-04-06+21%3A07%3A01.344156R&S_TACT=&S_CMP=

Comment: it would be better to include that comment in your post: you can always edit your own posts. It would also be good to accept your own answer (click the V).

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed my own problem.  The trick was to run the 64 bit SDK installer in compatibility mode on the server (by right-clicking on the installer and selecting "Troubleshoot Compatibility").  The installer then runs in Windows 7 mode and installs the ODBC drivers correctly.  I did nothing to make the ifxoledbc provider show up under Linked Servers in SSMS.  Once the ODBC was set up, I used that DSN to connect to the Cisco Informix database.  I did not use the driver directly.